# Unzip & Rename a File in One Command

Tags: zip

I have a zip file that contains a CSV and I would like to unzip that into a specific folder and rename the file the same as the zip file name. For example.,

I have a zip file named: youtube_videos.csv.zip and I would like to unzip it to a certain folder called target and rename the file in that folder to youtube-videos.csv. I have it, but in two lines as below:

```
unzip datasets/youtube_videos.csv.zip -d target 
mv target/videos_data.csv target/youtube_videos.csv
```

Is there a one liner that could be used?

Comment: Why do you need a one liner? It can complicate things unnecessarilly.

Comment: Is that good enough what I did?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it. I posted an answer for a one liner, but as you can see, there are complications.

Comment: why don't just use `unzip datasets/youtube_videos.csv.zip -d target; mv target/videos_data.csv target/youtube_videos.csv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one liner option, but it doesn't rename the file, it outputs its contents to stdout. Also maybe can't be used with the `-d` option (I can't make it work):

```
$ unzip -p datasets/youtube_videos.csv.zip videos_data.csv > target/youtube_videos.csv
```

Or if there's just one file inside the zip, you can omit the name of the zipped files:

```
$ unzip -p datasets/youtube_videos.csv.zip > target/youtube_videos.csv
```

---

The option `-p` does, according to the manual:

> `-p`     extract  files  to  pipe (stdout).  Nothing but the file data is sent to stdout, and the files are always extracted in binary format, just as they are stored
> (no conversions).

Answer (score 1):

With libarchive `bsdtar`:

```
bsdtar -xvvf youtube_videos.csv.zip -C target -'s/videos_data/youtube_videos/g'
```

Would extract the archive into the `target` directory with `videos_data` `s`ubstituted with `youtube_videos` in the name of archive members.

(note that the `target` directory must exist beforehand).